# Simplest Feynman diagram with fully detailed corresponding calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, education

I have look into a dozens of graduate textbooks so far (very likely not the best ones) and I haven’t been able to find a case, in which all of the following requirements are satisfied at the same time:

1. A Feynman diagram corresponding to the most simple practical situation
2. The detailed analytical (and corresponding numerical value) solution of (1) where we should fall back on a famous trivial case/solution known by any undergraduate student

Any feedback, lectures or recommendations would be greatly appreciated